# forbidding users from accessing each others accounts in Symfony2 using fosuserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

i would like to know how should i customize the firewall so the users cannot access any profile other than theirs by using the fosUser Bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're mixing concerns here. The **[FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)** allows you to manage users and common **user management** tasks (reset password and the like).

On the other hand, the **firewall**, is the part of the Symfony Security component which decides whether you're **authenticated enough** to access a given resource.

But I think that what you are really after is **[authorisation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html)** to resources, which is also part of the Security component, but it's not the firewall. The idea is that once you pass the firewall, an authentication Token is granted to the current user. Beware, this token could also mean that the user is not authenticated at all. This Token is very useful for what you want to do, which is basically decide if the current user can access a given resource.

This leads us to [Voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html#voters). Voters are units of logic that given a Token and some metadata are able to determine whether the Token is authorised for that resource.

So at the end of the day, if you're running a multi-tenant application, a common pattern is to associate almost every entity to the account/user it belongs to. Then checking whether the current user has permissions to view/edit/remove it should be trivial.